# Angular 16 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular

I have the above error message when I try to use two-way binding in a Angular application.

```
<form>
 <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required [(ngModel)]="email" />
</form>
```

The code is in the loginComponent which was created in this folder: src/app/login.

I've imported forms in the app.module.ts like this :

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...
@NgModule({
...
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
...
providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

restarted the app, but the error is still there.

Please help me with this situation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The html to which the component belongs to must be a standalone component. If that is the case, you need to separately add `FormsModule` to the imports array!

```
@Component({
  selector: '<<some-component>>',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  ...
})
```

Comment: Yess, that worked just fine! Thank you very much for your help and support! :D

Comment: No idea how to upvote or to give the green tick .. if you believe that...

Comment: Done! Thank you once again for your help and Have a great New Year! :D

Comment: @Collina Wishing you the same!